# Kotlin Companion Objection unresolved references

Tags: android, kotlin, companion-object

I have a Kotlin class with companion object which sees some fields of the parent class and does not see others. There is no option in Android Studio to import.

```
class A{
   var a = 1
   var b = 2
       companion object {
            a += 1// visible and imported
            b += 1// unresolved reference
       }
}
```

I do not want to create this variable inside the companion object.

Comment: cannot reproduce. Both give an error

Comment: a is not visible either inside companion object

Comment: @TimCastelijns  @mTak, Android Studio imported A class variables. In imports i see `import package.A.a`, but not  `import package.A.b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely incorrect.

You cannot access members of class inside companion object at all. But you can use companion`s members in your class.

If you see kotlin bytecode you will see that Companion object compiles to

```
   public static final class Companion {
      private Companion() {
      }

      // $FF: synthetic method
      public Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker $constructor_marker) {
         this();
      }
   }
```

Since Companion is `static class` it can exist without class where it is declared.

So in your case you can not access a and b because probably they are not exists.

They are not accessable for you too, but probably you cought IDE bug and it doesnt give you error

Comment: i can access A, but not B. maybe because issues during Kotlin compilation

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access instance variables from static context (companion), this is the same as Java code

Comment: but others are accessible... i see no difference in the two variables. maybe it is Android Studio issue that it does not import them

Answer (score 0):

> Android Studio imported A class variables. In imports i see import package.A.a, but not import package.A.b

`import package.A.a` simply doesn't make sense for a class property `a`, and companion object wouldn't require an `import` from the class it's companion to anyway. My best guess is that it's importing from an `object` in a different package.